# duplicated data with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, upsert

I am trying after crawling to do upsert with mongoose.
now  I am succeding save after crawling but it is duplicated after a few times.

now my function is to save data , how I can do upsert or something else that can help me

```js
const saveData = async (title, link, location, idJob,companyName)=>{
    try{
        const job= new Jobs({
            title:title,
             link:link,
              location:location, 
              _id:idJob,
              companyName: companyName
        })
        await job.save()
        console.log(job);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

That's what I'm trying i know it is not good but I don't know how to fix

```js
const saveData = async (title, link, location, idJob, companyName) => {
  try {
  
    await await job.findOneAndUpdate( {
      new: true,
      upsert: true
    });
    
    console.log(job);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you search the Mongoose documentation on how to do upserts?

Comment: yes i was trying but it is not working for me. Need two variables, one old and one new, and with me, it's not like that, I want to check  only if I was saving so update or doing nothing

Comment: If you were trying, you should post the code of that attempt, and what went wrong.

Comment: ok i uploaded my code

Comment: Please add it to your question, not as an answer :)

Comment: ok i add it to my question